# How to change text size and colour in listview in android?

Tags: android, textview

I binded one image and three textviews in listview.Now i want change the size and colour of each textview in listview.
is it possible........please help me.

Answer (score 0):

You will probably have a custom layout file for your list items in which you specify the image and the textviews. In this same layout file you can change the size and color of the text using the android:textSize and android:textColor attributes (see also http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html).